# problem in ValidationMessage helper

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-3

i use mvc3 razor
in my form i use this code:

```
@Html.ValidationMessage(Model.SMF_Name)
```

it's not working because it render

```
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="About" data-valmsg-replace="true">
<span htmlfor="About" generated="true" class="">Please fill this field.</span>
</span>
```

it's put the value instead of the name in the htmlfor attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SMF_Name)
```

Comment: yes i get error - Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type - i tried even m => Mode.SMF_Name

Comment: @eyalb, is `SMF_Name` a property on your model?

Comment: In this case `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SMF_Name)` should work.